# Raspberry Pi C++ error: invalid use of incomplete type

Tags: c++, c, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am writing a C++ program on the Raspberry Pi. I am using the [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/) library to get the current time and date to make it the title of a text file. For example, where I am the current date and time is 14:51 on the 23rd October 2015. So the name of the text file will be 20151023_14_51.txt. Here is the code:

```
FILE *f;
main(int argc, char *argv[]){
char dateiname[256]="";

time_t t = time(0);
struct tm * now = localtime(&t);

//Create and open file
sprintf(dateiname, "/home/raspbian/Desktop/%02d%02d%02d_%02d_%02d.txt",
            now->tm_year+1900,
            now->tm_mon+1, 
            now->tm_mday,
            now->tm_hour, 
            now->tm_min;

f = fopen(dateiname, "w");
```

My problem is that when I try to compile the program with gcc I am getting errors of the following nature:

> error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct main(int, char**)::tm'
>
> error: forward decleration of 'struct main(int, char**)::tm'

I also get this error at the beginning:

> error: 'localtime' was not declared in this scope

I did some research and found that people with similar problems weren't including sys/time.h but I have that included. Here is what I include:

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
```

Does anyone have any idea of what could be causing these errors or if I am missing anything? Thanks.

Comment: You forgot `#include <time.h>`. Put that in and report back. Try to avoid including `sys/` includes directly

Comment: ok so should i have both, or just the time.h?

Comment: C++ does not support implicit `int`. You need to write `int main()` or `auto main() -> int`.

Comment: @M.M yes that was the problem, thankyou!

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf yeah I just forgot to write it, thanks though

Comment: @oodan123 Are you sure this is C++? You're not using the C++ standard library at all or any features specific to C++.

Comment: Yeah my problem was that I didn't realise that sys/time.h and time.h are different includes

Comment: @PCLuddite "features not specific to C++" are still part of C++.

Comment: @M.M Never said they weren't, but the code reads more like C code than C++ code. It's bad practice to use the C header names in C++, and it's also strange to use C file io functions in C++. Sure it could compile in C++, but it would probably make for a better C program than a C++ program.

Comment: Disagree, C++ is a multi-paradigm language. C-style programs is one of those paradigms.

Comment: @M.M Yes, C++ is multi-paradigm, and this includes C-style code. I was just asking if the OP intended to make this a C program, or if they understand the distinction because I don't think this post needs both C and C++ tags. (The fact that functions don't default to `int` in C++ also indicates that this is C). But we're getting away from the original question, so I won't say anything more to this.

Comment: OK. I took "I am writing a C++ program" to mean that they intended to write C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `struct tm` is defined by either `#include <time.h>`,  or by `#include <ctime>` and using `std::tm` for the name.